# Copy sheet then move it to a closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a sheet then move the copy to an existing but closed workbook.

I tried code found here but it would not move the copied sheet to the closed workbook.

The code below won't copy the source sheet but instead copies the first sheet of of the destination workbook.

```vb
Sub CopySheet1()
    
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim targetWBPath As String
    Dim targetWB As Workbook
    Dim targetWS As Worksheet
    
    SheetName = InputBox("Type the sheet name, you want to copy:", "Copy Sheet")
    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    targetWBPath = 'D:\Users\User\Desktop\REPORTS\8Z-XF010CS\CTIC\October Filter PM\Current Transformer Inspection Checklist.xlsx'
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set targetWB = Workbooks.Open(targetWBPath)
    
    ActiveSheet.Move Before:=targetWB.Sheets(targetWB.Sheets.Count)
    
    ActiveSheet.Name = 'SheetName'
    
    targetWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox 'Done'``
End Sub
```

Comment: Let's see the code (as text) you have up to the point it needs to get copied. You need to supply the full path to open the workbook. Then copy the sheet, save the workbook, and close it again. Finally, a message box should inform you of success. Note that copying and moving are two different operations.

Comment: I have my code here. but instead of copying from source then send it to my destination. it copies the first sheet of the destination.

Comment: @VBasic2008 the code i have above does not copy the sheet from my source but instead it copies the destination 1st Sheet.

Comment: That is because after you open a workbook, the sheet that was active the last time before saving the workbook becomes the active sheet. You should use a variable for the selected sheet.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy (Move) Sheet to a Closed Workbook

```vb
Sub CopySheetToClosedWorkbook()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy Sheet to Closed Workbook"
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine

    ' Constants
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Test\Test.xlsx"
    
    ' Source
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ssh As Object: Set ssh = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(DST_FILE_PATH)
    
    ' Copy as last sheet:
    ssh.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
    ' or as first sheet:
    'ssh.Copy Before:=dwb.Sheets(1)
    ' Replace 'Copy' with 'Move' if you don't need the sheet in the source.
    
    ' Save and close.
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set dwb = Nothing
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Sheet copied.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop
        If Not dwb Is Nothing Then dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    MsgBox "Run-time error'" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**Edit**

```vb
Sub CopySheet1()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Copy Sheet to Closed Workbook"
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const DST_FILE_PATH As String = "D:\Users\User\Desktop\" _
        & "REPORTS\8Z-XF010CS\CTIC\October Filter PM\" _
        & "Current Transformer Inspection Checklist.xlsx"
     
    ' Retrieve input.
    Dim SheetName As String: SheetName = InputBox( _
        "Enter the sheet name you want to copy:", PROC_TITLE)

    ' Source
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If the code is in another workbook, instead, use:
    'Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Dim ssh As Object:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ssh = swb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If ssh Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The sheet """ & SheetName & """ doesn't exist.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dFileName As String: dFileName = Dir(DST_FILE_PATH)
    
    If Len(dFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The destination file is no longer located at """ _
            & DST_FILE_PATH & """!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(DST_FILE_PATH)

    ' Copy.

    ' Copy as the one before the last sheet:
    ssh.Move Before:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
    ' or as last sheet:
    'ssh.Move After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
    ' or as first sheet:
    'ssh.Move Before:=dwb.Sheets(1)
    ' Replace 'Move' with 'Copy' if you want to keep the source sheet.
    
    ' Perform additional operations.
    
    Dim dsh As Object: Set dsh = dwb.ActiveSheet
    
    If TypeOf dsh Is Worksheet Then ' i.e. it's not a chart
        With dsh.UsedRange
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .EntireRow.AutoFit
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End If
    
    If dsh.Name <> SheetName Then ' case-sensitive
        On Error Resume Next ' if a sheet with the same name exists
           dsh.Name = SheetName
        On Error GoTo ClearError
        If dsh.Name <> SheetName Then
            MsgBox "Could not rename sheet """ & dsh.Name & """ to """ _
                & SheetName & """!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Save and close.
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set dwb = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Sheet """ & SheetName & """ copied.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop
        If Not dwb Is Nothing Then dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    MsgBox "Run-time error'" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: I had an error on the constant and destination part of this.

Comment: Which errors (number and description) and on which lines?

Comment: @PEpz I've added another version.